# Prove Derivative

Tags: calculus, derivatives

If  $y = e^{2x}$, show that $y'' + y' - 6y = 0$.

$y'$ is $2e^{2x}$

$y''$ is $4e^{2x}$

I am not sure what method I have to use to prove this is true.

Comment: You've done all the work. Just plug the values in.$4e^{2x}+2e^{2x}-6e^{2x}=0$.

Comment: I plug in the y value to the 6y is that right? Basically $6e^{2x}$

Comment: Yes. Since $y=e^{2x}, \ - 6y=-6e^{2x}.$

Comment: Thanks Kman!!!!

Answer (score 4):

Plug in the values: $y''+y'-6y=4e^{2x}+2e^{2x}-6e^{2x}=6e^{2x}-6e^{2x}=0$

Comment: Yep figured it out. Thanks for the assist